# How do I find out the kernel version I am running?

Tags: command-line, kernel

> The path to previous driver is
> usually `/lib/modules/<kernel-version>/kernel/net/wireless`

I need this info so I can finish updating my STA Broadcom wireless. However, I'm a noob at Ubuntu and I'm not sure how to find the kernel version or kernel.

I checked `/lib/modules/` and found this:

```
2.6.27-10-generic  2.6.32-30-generic  2.6.32-34-generic  2.6.32-38-generic
2.6.27-7-generic   2.6.32-31-generic  2.6.32-35-generic  3.2.0-54-generic
2.6.28-19-generic  2.6.32-32-generic  2.6.32-36-generic  3.2.0-54-generic-pae
2.6.31-23-generic  2.6.32-33-generic  2.6.32-37-generic
```

Which one is the running kernel?

Another question. Is there a snippet so I don't have to cut and paste?

Thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

**Well there are multiple ways to find the kernel version**

Open terminal and execute:

```
uname -r
```

It would display something like:

```
3.8.0-30-generic
```

You can get further information on the current kernel with

```
uname -a
```

It would display something like:

```
Linux saurav-P4I45Gx-PE 3.8.0-30-generic #44~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 23 17:33:45 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Another way to know the kernel version is to open [Synaptic Package Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) and search for `linux image`. You have to check for the installed `Kernel` version.

Another way to find version of installed kernels is to run this command:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image | grep ii
```

or for just the version strings:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image | grep ii | awk '{print $3}'
```

The latest kernel (the one with the highest version number) will boot by default, so if you have rebooted since the last kernel update, and you have not made adjustments to boot into a kernel other than the default, then you can be reasonably confident that the highest version number displayed will be the version of the running kernel, but you should use `uname` for more reliable information.

Answer (score 93):

`uname -a` and `uname -r` will give you the information of the kernel used.

Comment: Note: if you are putting `uname -r` in a script, remember to strip the potential '-Microsoft' suffix in order to support Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). See [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2363) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/423)

Answer (score 31):

The official version of an Ubuntu kernel is found in the `/proc/version_signature` file (mainline kernels may lack this file, in which case `uname -r` is sufficient).

This file contains both the full Ubuntu version of the kernel and the mainline version on which it is based. The first field is always Ubuntu, the second field is the Ubuntu kernel version, and the final field is the upstream version:

```
$ cat /proc/version_signature
Ubuntu 2.6.35-6.9-generic 2.6.35-rc3
```

This and many questions just like it are answered in [Ubuntu Kernel Team's wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel) specifically the [FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/FAQ).

Comment: `cat /proc/version_signature` gives: `cat: /proc/version_signature: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden` on Ubuntu Precise Pangolin 12.04. This: `cat /proc/version` works.

Comment: `/proc/version_signature` seems to have disappeared in 4.3 (from the kernel-team mainline package archive), and `/proc/version` isn't a replacement; it has no upstream info.

Answer (score 11):

On systems that follow the [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) you should be able to get the kernel information with the following command:

```
cat /proc/version
```

Also, you can see other kernels that you have installed on your system and may be able to boot into with GRUB or another bootloader by using the following command:

```
ls /boot/vmlinuz*
```

Answer (score 8):

if you don't want to open a terminal, you can view your kernel version using `gnome-system-monitor`. Look for the system monitor in the menu and look in the first tab *System*.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use the two following commands:

```
uname -r
```

for version - output like:

```
3.5.0.17-generic
```

and

```
uname -v
```

for update time - output like:

```
#-ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:32:08 UTC 2012
```